# Retrieve user current location using Google play service in not working

Tags: android

I'm using new Google API for retrieving current location, and I got the current location. However, if the location services are not enabled in the app by default, and if I enable any location service using location intend, the client does not reconnect, in `onActivityResult` method, and I cannot fetch the current location.

```
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(R.string.connected);
    System.out.println("error");
    startPeriodicUpdates();

    if (mUpdatesRequested) {
        startPeriodicUpdates();
    }

    if (!locationServiceEnabled)
        return;
    if(mLocationClient.isConnected()&& servicesConnected())
    {
        fetchlocation = new FetchingLocation(getActivity());
        // mLocationClient = new LocationClient(getActivity(), this,this );
        Location currentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();

        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" +
            mLocationClient.getLastLocation());

        latitude=currentLocation.getLatitude();
        System.out.println(currentLocation.getLatitude());
        System.out.println("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"
            + String.valueOf(latitude));
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

But I can't get the location. As the app crashes, it shows the error:

> client not connected wait for connect

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get longitude and latitude value and then juste use that function

```
public String ConvertPointToLocation(GeoPoint point) {   
    String address = "";
    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(
        getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    try {
      List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
        point.getLatitudeE6()  / 1E6, 
        point.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

      if (addresses.size() > 0) {
        for (int index = 0; 
    index < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); index++)
          address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(index) + " ";
      }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {        
      e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    return address;
  }
```

Refer to this tutorial 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112044/GPSLocator-App-to-Find-Current-Nearest-Location-us

Comment: my actual isuue is if enable the location services like Intent intent = new Intent(
      Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1); after i returned to the app onActivity Result canot get the location ,because of location client is not connected.when try to reconnect but no use

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void setLatLong(double lat, double lng) {
    Longitude = lng;
    Latitude = lat;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    return Latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return Longitude;
}

public void getLocation() {

    locManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Utility obj = new Utility(context);
    if (obj.isGPSAvailable() && obj.isInternetAvailable())
    {

        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0, locListener);

        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0, 0, locListener);
    } 
    else

        Toast.makeText(context, "Internet or GPS not available",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (locManager != null) 
    {
        Location loc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(loc!=null)
        {
            setLatLong(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());

        }
        else
        {
             loc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
             if(loc!=null)
                {
                    setLatLong(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());

                }
        }
    }
}
```

Use above code for retrieving current location and you could get more help @ following link:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html